# How to calculate bounding rectangles size for a DOM element on which CSS transform matrix is applied? Without using Element.getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV who has been transformed using a matrix.

I need to calculate some information for its bounding rectangles size.

Specifically I need found out:
Width, Height, Rotation (deg from the matrix)

I cannot use
[Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

I am manly interesting in a math solution, assuming that I have all the data needed to perform the rendering of div in advance (like: top, left position) any feedbacks is welcome.

In the example, the green box is a visual rappresentation of the dimension I need to found out.

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: matrix(0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707107, 34.6482);
}

#result {
  position: absolute;
  height: 282.8427734375px;
  left: 57.871490478515625px;
  top: 93.22679901123047px;
  width: 282.8428039550781px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: _"I cannot use Element.getBoundingClientRect()"_ Why ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I need to minimalism DOM querying for my application, in this question I had simplified my use case. I need a Math solution if possible, so I can find the right dimensions without DOM operations.

Comment: What do you mean by "without DOM operations" ?

Comment: See http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Answer (score 1):

When you say "without DOM operations" I assume that you have all the data needed to perform the calculation by hand in advance. Specifically, you have the `(left, top)` coordinates and `width/height` dimensions of the pre-transformed rectangle, and you also have the details of each transformation that was applied to the rectangle, and in the correct order. In this case, I would first build four points as follows, which represents the pre-transformed rectangle:

- `p1 = (left, top)`
- `p2 = (left + width, top)`
- `p3 = (left, top + height)`
- `p4 = (left + width, top + height)`

Then I would apply the transformation chain to each of these four points, to get `p1'`, `p2'`, `p3'`, `p4'`.

Then I would run over each `p'`, and max/min the `top/left` coordinates of all of them:

- `max_top`
- `min_top`
- `max_left`
- `min_left`

Now, from that information I can derive that:

- `(min_left, min_top)` will give us the top-left point of the bounding rect.
- `(max_left - min_left, max_top - min_top)` will give us the dimensions of the bounding rect.

However, It would be easier if you could just query for the element's transformation matrix, and break its components into floats. Then use a JS math library (such as [numericJS](http://www.numericjs.com/)) to build a transformation matrix out of these components, and use it to transform your points.

Here is a snippet that can be used to extract a numericJS matrix out of an element's CSS `transform` property:

```
getTransformationMatrix: function (element) {
    var transform = element.css('transform');

    // Verify that the returned result is valid
    if (transform && transform !== "none" && transform !== "") {
        // The returned string from 'element.css('transform')' has the following template - 'matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty)'. We would like to extract the values of a, b, c and d,
        // in order to use them to construct a Matrix object which will represent the following matrix:
        //   a b tx
        // ( c d ty )
        //   0 0 1
        // For more information, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
        var transformValues = transform.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');

        var a = parseFloat(transformValues[0]);
        var c = parseFloat(transformValues[1]);
        var b = parseFloat(transformValues[2]);
        var d = parseFloat(transformValues[3]);
        var tx = parseFloat(transformValues[4]);
        var ty = parseFloat(transformValues[5]);

        return [[a, b, tx], [c, d, ty], [0, 0, 1]];
    }

    // return the identity matrix if no transformation is set on the element.
    return new [[1, 0 ,0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]];
}
```

You can now use it to transform a given point:

```
function getTransformedPoint(matrix, point) {
   return numeric.dot(matrix, [p.left, p.top, 1]);
}

var matrix = getTransformationMatrix(element);
transformedP1 = getTransformedPoint(matrix, p1);
transformedP2 = getTransformedPoint(matrix, p2);
transformedP3 = getTransformedPoint(matrix, p3);
transformedP4 = getTransformedPoint(matrix, p4);
```

Comment: Have you included the rotation on your example?

Comment: No, I was referring to the general case. If it is all about rotation, then I would first translate all my points by (-rotationCenter.left, - rotationCenter.top), then I will rotate all my points by X degrees using a rotation rotation transformation, then I will translate all the points back by (rotationCenter.left, rotationCenter.top).

Comment: @rovy could you please create a jsfiddle for your solution?

Comment: @rovy did you have time to have a look at this? Thanks in advance!